# MemoryCache: Why is this integration test failing? UpdateCallBack looks like it's broken

Tags: c#, caching, integration-testing

In a sane world, I would have expected the `UpdateCallBack` property to increment my collection of arguments.  But it doesn't: in the final line of this test, the `updateArguments` collection is expected to be 3 (twice for each `Set` call and once for the `Remove` call), but it is empty.

The test is rough and ready, but it should be enough to illustrate that something odd is happening.

Or that I am missing something obvious.

EDIT: This is getting stranger.  Based on the question [MemoryCache UpdateCallback not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650614/memorycache-updatecallback-not-working), which says that `Thread.Sleep` blocks the `MemoryCache.Default` object, I changed the original `Thread.Sleep(5000)` call to `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(10000)).Wait();`.  Then, if I comment out the call to `MemoryCache.Default.Remove()`, the `updateArguments` collection does indeed get incremented, but only once, and that is when the `"PersonKey"` cached item expires.  The two `Set()` and one `Remove()` calls are ignored completely.  I'm having a "What the heck" moment.

```
[Test]
public void TheMemoryCacheMaintainsAMemberAndInvokesTheUpdateCallback()
{
    var person = new Person { GivenName = "Rob", LastName = "Lyndon"};
    var givenName = person.GivenName;
    var lastName = person.LastName;

    var updateArguments = new List<CacheEntryUpdateArguments>();

    MemoryCache.Default.Set("PersonKey", person, CreateNewPolicy(updateArguments));
    var cachedItem = MemoryCache.Default.Get("PersonKey") as Person;
    Assert.IsNotNull(cachedItem);
    Assert.That(cachedItem.GivenName, Is.EqualTo(givenName));
    Assert.That(cachedItem.LastName, Is.EqualTo(lastName));

    person.LastName = "Lyndon - Updated";
    MemoryCache.Default.Set("PersonKey", member, CreateNewPolicy(updateArguments));
    cachedItem = MemoryCache.Default.Get("PersonKey") as Person;
    Assert.IsNotNull(cachedItem);
    Assert.That(cachedItem.GivenName, Is.EqualTo(givenName));
    Assert.That(cachedItem.LastName, Is.EqualTo(lastName + " - Updated"));

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(10000)).Wait();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Assert.That(updateArguments.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));
}

private static CacheItemPolicy CreateNewPolicy(ICollection<CacheEntryUpdateArguments> updateArguments)
{
    return new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(1),
            UpdateCallback = args => updateArguments.Add(args)
        };
}
```

Comment: Where does it fail for you Rob and what's the failure message?

Comment: It fails on the last line.  `updateArguments` should be 3 (incremented twice for the `Set` operations and once for the `Remove` operation.

Comment: Looks like you might be expecting the `updateArguments` parameter of `CreateNewPolicy` to be being passed by `ref`. If it's being passed by value then changes made to it inside of `CreateNewPolicy` won't persist outside of the scope of that method.

Comment: But if I put a breakpoint on the `updateArguments.Add()` call, it never gets hit.  I'll drop the last `Remove` statement and see what happens.

Comment: When does `UpdateCallback` get executed and who executes it?

Comment: It should be called by the `CacheItemPolicy`, which is set up in the call to `MemoryCache.Default.Set("MemberKey", member, CreateNewPolicy(updateArguments))`.

Comment: Some side note :- Since you are accessing the caching infrastructure/some kind of a storage, this is not a Unit Test, it is an Integration Test.

Comment: Ha ha -- good point Raj.  And I'm usually a stickler for those details.  I'll edit if possible.

Comment: @RobLyndon Thanks. I removed tag 'Unit Tests' and add the 'Integration Tests' if you don't mind :)